# Searching palindromes with grep -E (egrep)

Tags: regex, bash, unix, grep

**UPD**: according to [Ed Morton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77861446/23204874) the issue isn't related to `-E` option only.

Reading The Unix Programming Environment by Brian W. Kernighan and Rob Pike.

Working on an exercise, where one should find all palindromes in a wordlist using `grep -E`.

The most concise solution I've been able to find online and understand would be

`'^(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?).?\5\4\3\2\1$'`, which should find all palindromes up to 11 characters.

For some reason though, grep in my terminal gives me results that I can't explain:

```bash
me@machine:~/test$ cat sample
a
ab
abba
abcdef
abcba
zufolo
me@machine:~/test$ grep -E '^(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?).?\5\4\3\2\1$' sample
a
abba
abcba
zufolo
me@machine:~/test$ grep -E '^(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?).?\4\3\2\1$' sample
a
abba
abcba
```

Why would it add `zufolo` to the results (while not coloring any matches as it does with the actual palindromes)? Why does `zufolo` disappear when I reduce the regex to up to 9 characters?
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zweqe.png)

Does it have anything to do with my setup (the most standard one)?

```bash
me@machine:~/test$ ls -l /proc/$$/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me 0 jan 15 18:37 /proc/3528/exe -> /usr/bin/bash
me@machine:~/test$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 6.5.0-14-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-110) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #14~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Nov 20 18:15:30 UTC 2
```

P.S. `zufolo` is from `wamerican-insane` where I'm actually testing it. There are plenty of others like `xenian`, `tartar`.

I tried researching online, modifying regex, but can't get my head around this one.

Comment: If i remove the question mark in the middle it works, but returns only the palindromes with odd length
`'^(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?).\5\4\3\2\1$'`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has to do with the optional matches, but I don't have an explanation, because you anchor the whole thing at start and end of line. Really interesting. Other inputs that break: `xxxxaa` and `abcdxx`. Seems like only inputs of length 6 trigger the strange behavior

Comment: Looks like a bug in `-E` option. If you try `-P` then it is fine

Comment: `zupas` doesn't work too. But until length 5 seems to be all good on `wamerican-insane`

Comment: Interesting. Just a few observations: (1) I can reproduce your findings with Gnu grep. (2) Running BSD Grep does not produce a single match with your input file. (3) Using as pattern `'^(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?).?\4\1\1\1\1$'`  or `'^(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?).?\5\1\1\1\1$'` still matches your _zufolo_, while `'^(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?).?\3\1\1\1\1$'` does not match it.

Comment: if it helps, `perl -ne '/^(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?).?\5\4\3\2\1/ && print' <pals` doesn't seem to have this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strangely enough, removing the `$` from the end of the regexp (i.e. making it less restrictive) produces fewer matches, which is the opposite of what it should do:

a) With the `$` at the end of the regexp:

```
$ grep -E '^(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?).?\5\4\3\2\1$' sample
a
abba
abcba
zufolo
```

b) Without the `$` at the end of the regexp:

```
$ grep -E '^(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?).?\5\4\3\2\1' sample
a
abba
abcba
```

It's not just GNU grep that behaves strangely, GNU sed has the same behavior from the question when just matching with `sed -nE '/.../p' sample` as GNU `grep` does AND sed behaves differently if we're just doing a match vs if we're doing a match + replace.

For example here's `sed` doing a match+replacement and behaving the same way as `grep` above:

a) With the `$` at the end of the regexp:

```
$ sed -nE 's/^(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?).?\5\4\3\2\1$/&/p' sample
a
abba
abcba
zufolo
```

b) Without the `$` at the end of the regexp:

```
$ sed -nE 's/^(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?).?\5\4\3\2\1/&/p' sample
a
abba
abcba
```

but here's sed just doing a match and behaving differently from any of the above:

a) With the `$` at the end of the regexp (note the extra `ab` in the output):

```
$ sed -nE '/^(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?).?\5\4\3\2\1$/p' sample
a
ab
abba
abcba
zufolo
```

b) Without the `$` at the end of the regexp (note the extra `ab` and `abcdef` in  the output):

```
$ sed -nE '/^(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?).?\5\4\3\2\1/p' sample
a
ab
abba
abcdef
abcba
zufolo
```

Also interestingly this:

```
$ sed -nE 's/^(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?).?\5\4\3\2\1$/<&>/p' sample
```

outputs:

```
<a>
<abba>
<abcba>
<>zufolo
```

the last line of which means the regexp is apparently matching the start of the line and ignoring the `$` end-of-string metachar present in the regexp!

The odd behavior isn't just associated with using `-E`, though, if I remove `-E` and just use [POSIX compliant BREs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) then:

a) With the `$` at the end of the regexp:

```
$ grep '^\(.\{0,1\}\)\(.\{0,1\}\)\(.\{0,1\}\)\(.\{0,1\}\)\(.\{0,1\}\).\{0,1\}\5\4\3\2\1$' sample
a
abba
abcba
zufolo
```

```
$ sed -n 's/^\(.\{0,1\}\)\(.\{0,1\}\)\(.\{0,1\}\)\(.\{0,1\}\)\(.\{0,1\}\).\{0,1\}\5\4\3\2\1$/&/p' sample
a
abba
abcba
zufolo
```

b) Without the `$` at the end of the regexp:

```
$ grep '^\(.\{0,1\}\)\(.\{0,1\}\)\(.\{0,1\}\)\(.\{0,1\}\)\(.\{0,1\}\).\{0,1\}\5\4\3\2\1' sample
a
abba
abcba
```

```
$ sed -n 's/^\(.\{0,1\}\)\(.\{0,1\}\)\(.\{0,1\}\)\(.\{0,1\}\)\(.\{0,1\}\).\{0,1\}\5\4\3\2\1/&/p' sample
a
abba
abcba
```

and again just doing a match in sed below behaves differently from the sed match+replacements above:

a) With the `$` at the end of the regexp:

```
$ sed -n '/^\(.\{0,1\}\)\(.\{0,1\}\)\(.\{0,1\}\)\(.\{0,1\}\)\(.\{0,1\}\).\{0,1\}\5\4\3\2\1$/p' sample
a
ab
abba
abcba
zufolo
```

b) Without the `$` at the end of the regexp:

```
$ sed -n '/^\(.\{0,1\}\)\(.\{0,1\}\)\(.\{0,1\}\)\(.\{0,1\}\)\(.\{0,1\}\).\{0,1\}\5\4\3\2\1/p' sample
a
ab
abba
abcdef
abcba
zufolo
```

The above shows that, given the same regexp, sed is apparently matching different strings depending on whether it's doing a substitution or not.

So, there appear to be bugs in GNU grep and GNU sed without the `-E`. Or maybe the above is all just undefined behavior given those regexps and so any grep or sed can do whatever they like with them.

```
$ grep --version | head -1
grep (GNU grep) 3.11

$ sed --version | head -1
sed (GNU sed) 4.9
```

Comment: My Git Bash dumps core if run without the `$` at the end, reporting `assertion "num >= 0" failed: file "regexec.c", line 1394, function: pop_fail_stack` if anyone cares. With the tail anchor it includes `zufolo` *unless* I use `-w` or `-x`. Converting to Basic rather than Extended doesn't change the behavior for me either. It also seems to do the same or similar with `xufolo` or `xorol`, as random examples I tried. This is pretty interesting.

Comment: @PaulHodges confirmed, I get the same from git bash even WITH the `$` at the end, e.g. `grep -E '^(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?).?\5\4\3\2\1' sample` and `grep -E '^(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?)(.?).?\5\4\3\2\1$' sample` both output `a
assertion "num >= 0" failed: file "regexec.c", line 1394, function: pop_fail_stack
                                                                                  Aborted (core dumped)`. That's using `$ echo $BASH_VERSION` -> `5.2.15(1)-release` and `$ grep --version` -> `grep (GNU grep) 3.0`

Comment: I REALLY wonder if this is just undefined behavior.....

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward, though. Odd that it *isn't*? Makes me wish I had time to dig through the codebase with a debugger, lol

Comment: With 5 "1 char or none" matches in a row then 1 or no dots, then 5 backreferences that may or may not have matched anything the possibilities of what that might match is confusing but the fact it's anchored with `^` and `$` make it pretty clear it shouldn't be matching the non-existent character at the start of the `zufolo` line. And the core dumps in git-bash are less than ideal :-).

Comment: I do see at https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Known-Bugs.html that they mention multiple bugs related to backreferences but say " Luckily, back-references are rarely useful and it should be little trouble to avoid them in practical applications." but that sentiment certainly doesn't apply to sed.

Comment: @PaulHodges FYI I emailed the GNU grep and sed bug report lists, we'll see what comes of that.

Comment: Thanks for your time spent researching this. Good thing bug reports are sent.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the actual answer to your question is, there's nothing wrong with your regex; you appear to have uncovered a bug in `grep`.

Demo of the regex working: https://regex101.com/r/RueEm0/1

(Though keep in mind that regex101.com does not support POSIX ERE specifically. The demo uses PCRE2 which is what the site offers by default; but the regex does not use any PCRE features.)